# Error building custom iOS Framework in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, build, ios-frameworks

This is the first time I have ever tried to create a custom iOS Framework.  I'm trying to create custom iOS Framework using xCode by following this [tutorial](http://jaym2503.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-create-custom-ios-framework.html).  I have gotten all the way to the very last step (Step 12).

```
Step 12: Build Project with Aggregate scheme

Select Aggregate("UniversaliOS") Scheme 
Select iOS device
Build Project (⌘-B)
```

But the build fails with a Shell Script Invocation Error:  Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1.  The error details are:

```
ditto: can't get real path for source
lipo: can't create temporary output file: /Users/pdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InnerID-iOS-SDK-dgyjuudeootshidhpzlejhbyqvco/Build/Products/InnerID-iOS-SDK-Bundle.framework/InnerID-iOS-SDK-Bundle.lipo (No such file or directory)
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

I have absolutely no clue as to what to do now.  Any suggestions?  I can provide the PhaseScriptExecution dump if necessary.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct shell script to be used (for swift).

```
CONFIG=Release

# Step 1. Make sure the output directory exists
UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIG}-universal
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

# Step 2. Build Device and Simulator versions

codebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration     ${CONFIG} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build

xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIG} -sdk iphonesimulator -arch x86_64 -arch i386 BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build

# Step 3. Copy the framework structure to the universal folder.  Subsequently copy the files of the swiftmodule (in Modules directory) of -iphonesimulator to the swiftmodule of universal framework directory.

cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIG}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"

cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIG}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule/" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule"

# Step 4. Create universal binary file using lipo and place the combined executable in the copied framework directory

lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIG}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIG}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}"
```

If you still have any doubts, you can look at the [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZ5lUkEzlGM).

Comment: This will help someone.  But I'm not using swift.  Thank you.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't compile your iOSBundle for both(Step 10) and directly attempt to merge both iOS simulator and device(Step 12).

Basically what Step 10 is doing?
Its's just creating Framework for both Simulator and Device, So for some reason your build folder gets empty and your script not able find framework for iOS-Simulator and Device both or any one.

Quick resolution :
Perform Step 10, one more time before Step 12, this will create iOS-simulator Framework and Device Framework both, After that build project for your Aggregate scheme, this will merge both framework.

You can find all three(iOS-Simulaor, Device, Merged) framework at below 
/Users/jaym/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSFramework-doeqysadgntrrlguuvcivuhapnlr/Build/Products/

In your case, /Users/pdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InnerID-iOS-SDK-dgyjuudeootshidhpzlejhbyqvco/Build/Products/